# Zookeeper set up for Kaa

Tags: kaa

I'm trying to set up kaa v0.10.0 on ubuntu 14.04 LTS. To install zookeper I used the following command.

`sudo apt-get install zookeeper`

But it fails to start when I start the kaa-node service.
But when I install the package zookeeperd (seen in older kaa versions documentation `sudo apt-get install zookeeperd`), it works fine.

Can anyone please clarify which is the correct zookeeper package for kaa 0.10? - **zookeeper** or **zookeeperd**

Answer (score 0):

From few of my experiences in deploying Kaa, I don't think Zookeeper will start automatically after installation, perhaps you can start it manually before starting Kaa-node.

Comment: From their documentation its mentioned that we can check the zookeeper status after running the command `sudo apt-get install zookeeper`, I think no additional commands required to run zookeper. We can zee that for mongodb. i.e, `sudo service mongod start` after installing it

Comment: Yup, you certainly can check its status after installing zookeeper. So did `$ netstat -ntlp | grep 2181` return anything that could indicates zookeeper has been started?

Comment: Nothing :( . But if we need to start it manually it should be there in their documentation. Also which is the required package **zookeeper** or **zookeeperd**?

Comment: idk, maybe the documentation is out of date, and you can send a patch to update it. You can try to start the zookeeper using `$sudo /usr/share/zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh start`, before starting kaa-node.